# Windows Phone App textbox binding don't work

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, binding

I'm working on my first Windows Phone 7 App and have the problem that a binding on a textbox don't work and i really don't know why. Other bindings works perfect.

If the Date is changed, the text in the textbox should also be changed.

Xaml:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ZodiacText" Text="{Binding Path=ZodiacString, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" />
```

And the code behind:

```
public DateTime Date
{
    get { return date; }
    set
    {
        if (value != this.date)
        {
            this.date = value;
            setActualDate(this.date);

            update();

            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs("NewDate"));
            }
        }
    }
}
public void update()
{
    zodiac = MoonCalculus.getZodiac();
   ...
    ZodiacString = zodiac;
}
public String ZodiacString
{
    get { return zodiacString; }
    set
    {
        if (zodiacString != value)
        {
            zodiacString = AppResources.ResourceManager.GetString(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the OnNavigatedTo codes, I had a similar problem once that I think now you have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting rid of `update()`, and get rid of the setter for `ZodiacString`.

Two reasons - it's not needed, and 
In the getter, do the work of update. This is better then your current implementation too -- the value being used as a parameter for `AppResources.ResourceManager.GetString(value);` is 'code smell' because it's not making obvious it's true intentions. (using as a parameter rather than setting ZodiacString to it's value)

```
public DateTime Date
{
    get { return date; }
    set
    {
        if (value != this.date)
        {
            this.date = value;
            setActualDate(this.date);
RaisePropertyChanged("Date");
RaisePropertyChanged("NewDate");
RaisePropertyChanged("ZodiacString");

        }
    }
}


private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
}

public String ZodiacString
{
    get { 
zodiac = MoonCalculus.getZodiac();
   ...
return zodiac; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You're not raising `PropertyChanged` when `ZodiacString` is set
2. You have `Mode=OneWay`, which is the default anyway. You want `Mode=TwoWay`.

Comment: raising PropertyChanged doesn't make it work. I change the ImageSource of a Button dynamically with bindings too without raising it and that works.

I want Mode=OneWay, changings are only made from model to UI